# Android : Can ContentValues be used as Associated Arrays?

Tags: android

I am creating a SQLiteOpenHelper and want to send multiple column with columns as key and returned values as associated string. Cant find any associated arrays in Android except using HashMap. Can I use contentValues as associated arrays?

Comment: What's wrong with using `HashMap`?

Comment: Nothing. Just a bit new and don't know HashMap so well. LazyFellowAlert here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't described what you are trying to achieve very well, but there are two options:

1. Use `HashMap` (or any `Map` for that matter) - and put values in it:

   ```
   Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
   values.put("key1", "value1");
   values.put("key2", "value2");
   ```

   Then, when you need to get the values, retrieve them from the map.
2. You can use `ContentValues` - and put values in it.  The code would be pretty much the same.

Which option you choose depends on your preference and also on what you're trying to do.  If inside your SQLite Helper you are planning to use these values to insert/update records in a database, then you might as well just use `ContentValues` - otherwise you'd need to extract them from the `HashMap` and put into `ContentValues` anyway.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I want to send multiple column values to my MainActivity and want to fill up a fragment for User, based on those values. I was a confused with HashMaps and saw ContentValues while reading a tutorial for DBHelper class. Couldn't understand why not use ContentValues instead of HashMap as I searched and found no reference explaining the reason. So thought to get Expert advice on why not use ContentValues. I mean any issue etc.

Comment: Just discovered while reading ContentValue implementation that its in fact a HashMap<String, Object>. :)